# Is there a way to force a React component to rerender a child?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component `<ProductPrices>`:

```
  render() {
    if (this.props.currentProduct.id !== 'new' && !this.props.currentProductPrices) {
      this.props.fetchProductPrices(this.props.currentProduct.id);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{backgroundColor: 'gray', paddingLeft: '10px', paddingTop: '10px', paddingBottom: '5px'}}>
          <h1>Precios</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.props.currentProductPrices && this.props.currentProductPrices.map((price, index) => {
            console.log({detail: price});
            return (
              <ProductPricesEntry key={price.id} price={price} index={index} />
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

As you can see, `<ProductPrices>` contains a number of subcomponents `<ProductPricesEntry>`,  which amount is dynamic depending on Redux state variable `currentProductPrices`:

```
render() {
    console.log({entry: this.props.price});
    return (
      <div style={{display: 'flex', background: 'white', backgroundColor: 'lightgray', marginTop: '2px', paddingLeft: '10px', paddingTop: '10px', paddingBottom: '5px'}}>
        <div className='col-10'>
          <div fullWidth>
            <h3>{this.props.price.prices_table.name}</h3>
          </div>
          <div fullWidth style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            {this.props.price.current_price? 
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'><strong>{currencyFormatter.format(this.props.price.current_price)}</strong></div>:
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right', color: 'orange'}} className='col-4'>Ninguno</div>
            }
            {this.props.price.due_date?
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}} className='col-4'><strong>{this.props.price.due_date}</strong></div>:
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'orange'}} className='col-4'>Ninguno</div>
            }
            {this.props.price.next_price?
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'><strong>{currencyFormatter.format(this.props.price.next_price)}</strong></div>:
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right', color: 'orange'}} className='col-4'>Ninguno</div>
            }
          </div>
          <div fullWidth style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'>Actual</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}} className='col-4'>Vigencia</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'>Próximo</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='col-1'>
          <IconButton color="primary" aria-label={''.concat('update-price-', this.props.price.id)}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-edit zmdi-hc-fw" onClick={this.handleUpdateClick} />
          </IconButton>
          <Dialog fullWidth open={this.state.updateDialogOpen} arialabelledby={''.concat('update-price-', this.props.price.id)}>
            <DialogTitle id={"".concat("update-price-", this.props.price.id)}>Actualizar Precio</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContentText>
              <div style={{paddingLeft: '25px'}}><h2>{this.props.currentProductData.name}</h2></div>
              <div style={{paddingLeft: '25px'}}><h2>{this.props.price.prices_table.name}</h2></div>
            </DialogContentText>
            <DialogContent>
              <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="newPrice">Precio</InputLabel>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  id="newPrice"
                  name="newPrice"
                  value={this.state.newPrice}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <div fullWidth><TextField fullWidth label="Fecha" type="date" name="newDate" value={this.state.newDate} onChange={this.handleChange} /></div>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={this.handleDialogAcceptClick} name="accept" color="primary">
                  Aceptar
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.handleDialogCancelClick} name="cancel" color="secondary">
                  Cancelar
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have put `console.log()` statements right before calling `<ProductPricesEntry>` from `<ProductPrices>`, and inside `<ProductPricesEntry>` when rendering, and I can see that both `console.log()` statements are reached the first time, but the one inside `<ProductPricesEntry>`  is not reached if `this.props.currentProductPrices` changes:

[image]

This is the value of `this.props.currentPrices` that is different, and I can see the change on Redux Tools:

[image]

The problem is that `console.log()` statement inside `<ProductPricesEntry>` is never reached, which means that it does not rerenders, in despite that the Redux state value that changed is sent to the component as a props, and displayed inside.

I guess I am doing something wrong, but I can't find it.

**EDIT**
This is the *reducer* that changes the state that must cause the rerendering:

```
case UPDATE_PRODUCT_PRICE_SUCCESS: {
      if (state.currentPricesTable) {
        let currentPricesTableProducts = [...state.currentPricesTableProducts];
        let updatedProductIndex = currentPricesTableProducts.findIndex(product => product.id === action.payload.productPrice.id)
        currentPricesTableProducts[updatedProductIndex]['next_price'] = action.payload.productPrice.next_price;
        currentPricesTableProducts[updatedProductIndex]['due_date'] = action.payload.productPrice.start_date;

        return {
          ...state,
          currentPricesTableProducts: [...currentPricesTableProducts],
          alert: {type: ALERT_SUCCESS, message: "El precio se actualizó existosamente."},
          showMessage: true,
        }
      } else if (state.currentProduct) {
        let currentProductPrices = [...state.currentProductPrices];
        let updatedProductPriceIndex = currentProductPrices.findIndex(productPrice => productPrice.prices_table_product === action.payload.productPrice.prices_table_product)

        currentProductPrices[updatedProductPriceIndex].next_price = action.payload.productPrice.next_price;
        currentProductPrices[updatedProductPriceIndex].due_date = action.payload.productPrice.start_date;

        return {
          ...state,
          currentProductPrices: [...currentProductPrices],
          alert: {type: ALERT_SUCCESS, message: "El precio se actualizó existosamente."},
          showMessage: true,
        }
      } else {
        return {
          ...state
        }
      }
    }
```

As you can see, I replace the state variable `currentProductPrices` whit a brand new array.

I added a `console.log()` just before returning from the *reducer*, and I can see that the data is right. I can see the change:

[image]

Comment: currentProductPrices has to be new array for re-render. If something is changing inside, it wont cause re-render. Also dont forget to add key property to your ProductPricesEntry elements when you create them with map.

Comment: @EugeneMankovski I make an edition, please, check it.

Comment: Try putting console.log( ) into reducer right before second return where you return updated currentProductPrices. Also add key property to  <ProductPricesEntry price={price} index={index} key={price.id}/>

Comment: Also this.props.fetchProductPrices(this.props.currentProduct.id) should be called on new js cycle to not affect rendering. You can use setTimeout function or useEffect hook.

Comment: @EugeneMankovski I did both, and nothing.

Comment: Yes the code looks right as of now. It should work. Only other idea I have is that ProductPricesEntry may have some livecycle handlers preventing it from rendering.

Comment: @EugeneMankovski Not at all. No lifecycle handlers on component.

Comment: of I think I see it now. The problem is that you either need to use ternary operator or create helper function. I.e. this.props.currentProductPrices ? this.props.currentProductPrices.map.... : null. Or create a handler function {renderDetails()} where you check  this.props.currentProductPrices is not null and return rendered set of  <ProductPricesEntry>

Comment: Thanks for your time, @EugeneMankovski, but I have found a way around the problem. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could never make it work as it was, but I found a wait around the problem, and I am sharing it in case it was useful for anyone.

I basically connected `<ProductPricesEntry>` to Redux store instead of sending the data as props from the parent.

```
class ProductPricesEntry extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      updateDialogOpen: false,
      newPrice: null,
      newDate: null,
      price: null,
    }

    this.price = null;

    this.handleUpdateClick = this.handleUpdateClick.bind(this);
    this.handleDialogAcceptClick = this.handleDialogAcceptClick.bind(this);
    this.handleDialogCancelClick = this.handleDialogCancelClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdateClick = () => {
    this.setState({updateDialogOpen: true});
  }

  handleDialogAcceptClick = () => {
    this.props.updateProductPrice(
      this.price.prices_table_product, 
      this.price.prices_table.id,
      this.props.currentProductData.id,
      this.state.newPrice, this.state.newDate
    );

    let price = {...this.state.price};
    price.due_date = this.state.newDate;
    price.next_price = this.state.newPrice;
    this.setState({newPrice: null, newDate: null, updateDialogOpen: false, price: price});
  }

  handleDialogCancelClick () {
    this.setState({newPrice: null, newDate: null, updateDialogOpen: null});
  }

  handleChange (event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    this.price = this.props.currentProductPrices[this.props.index]
    return (
      <div key={this.props.index} style={{display: 'flex', background: 'white', backgroundColor: 'lightgray', marginTop: '2px', paddingLeft: '10px', paddingTop: '10px', paddingBottom: '5px'}}>
        <div className='col-10'>
          <div fullWidth>
            <h3>{this.price.prices_table.name}</h3>
          </div>
          <div fullWidth style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            {this.price.current_price? 
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'><strong>{currencyFormatter.format(this.price.current_price)}</strong></div>:
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right', color: 'orange'}} className='col-4'>Ninguno</div>
            }
            {this.price.due_date?
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}} className='col-4'><strong>{this.price.due_date}</strong></div>:
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'orange'}} className='col-4'>Ninguno</div>
            }
            {this.price.next_price?
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'><strong>{currencyFormatter.format(this.price.next_price)}</strong></div>:
              <div style={{textAlign: 'right', color: 'orange'}} className='col-4'>Ninguno</div>
            }
          </div>
          <div fullWidth style={{display: 'flex'}}>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'>Actual</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}} className='col-4'>Vigencia</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'right'}} className='col-4'>Próximo</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='col-1'>
          <IconButton color="primary" aria-label={''.concat('update-price-', this.price.id)}>
            <i className="zmdi zmdi-edit zmdi-hc-fw" onClick={this.handleUpdateClick} />
          </IconButton>
          <Dialog fullWidth open={this.state.updateDialogOpen} arialabelledby={''.concat('update-price-', this.price.id)}>
            <DialogTitle id={"".concat("update-price-", this.price.id)}>Actualizar Precio</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContentText>
              <div style={{paddingLeft: '25px'}}><h2>{this.props.currentProductData.name}</h2></div>
              <div style={{paddingLeft: '25px'}}><h2>{this.price.prices_table.name}</h2></div>
            </DialogContentText>
            <DialogContent>
              <FormControl fullWidth>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="newPrice">Precio</InputLabel>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  id="newPrice"
                  name="newPrice"
                  value={this.state.newPrice}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  startAdornment={<InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <div fullWidth><TextField fullWidth label="Fecha" type="date" name="newDate" value={this.state.newDate} onChange={this.handleChange} /></div>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={this.handleDialogAcceptClick} name="accept" color="primary">
                  Aceptar
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.handleDialogCancelClick} name="cancel" color="secondary">
                  Cancelar
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({inventory}) => {
  const {
    currentProduct,
    currentProductData,
    currentProductPrices,
  } = inventory

  return {
    currentProduct,
    currentProductData,
    currentProductPrices,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateProductPrice}) (ProductPricesEntry);
```

Now it works as intended.